# Aggregration join not working in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have three collections with following feilds

- productTbl

  -- productId

  -- productName

  -- categoryId

  -- vendorId

  .... so on
- categoryTbl

  -- categoryId

  -- categoryName
- VendorTbl

  -- VendorID

  -- VendorName

I have written below mongodb aggregrate lookup query

```
                 $pipeline = array(
                            array(
                                '$lookup' => array(
                                'from' => 'VendorTbl',
                                'localField' => 'vendorId',
                                'foreignField' => 'VendorID',
                                'as' => 'vendordetails'
                                      )
                                  ),

                                array(
                                '$lookup' => array(
                                'from' => 'categoryTbl',
                                'localField' => 'categoryId',
                                'foreignField' => 'categoryId',
                                'as' => 'categorydetails'
                                      )
                                  ),
                         );               

                    $output = $this->db->productTbl->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Now the above query is fetching all the feilds from product table but categorydetails and vendordetails are empty. I am not able to trace this issue. 
Please help!!!

The output is like

```
                     {"$id":"59941ea11d78596801000029"},"productId":14,"productName":"Pencils","vendorId":"2","categoryId":"5","quantity":"122","sellingPrice":"122","vendordetails":[],"categorydetails":[]
```

The actual document for category table is like

```
          {
             "categoryId": 18,
             "categoryName": "swdgvqaedeadsgsgdf",
          }
```

The actual document for vendor table is like

```
          {
           "_id": ObjectId("599413e01d78596409000029"),
            "VendorID": 3,
            "VendorName": "hydfyugjgfu",
          }
```

The actual document for product table is like

```
         {
          "_id": ObjectId("59941ec11d7859680100002a"),
           "productId": 15,
           "productName": "Pens",
           "vendorId": "3",
           "categoryId": "7",
           ...
           ...
         }
```

Comment: Show the actual documents you think should be related. But the usual reason for an empty array from a `$lookup` result is that the two fields in question in fact have different data types, and therefore do not match.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Then you should be looking at it and realizing that `"VendorID": 3` and `"vendorId": "3"` actually differ in "type". One is numeric and the other is a "string". They both need to the of the same type or they do not match. I suggest converting your strings to numeric values.

Comment: Thankyou so much...